# Display "" in a string output

Tags: c#, c++, string

I want to display sth like

```
string test1 = "test2";
```

so i would like this to be displayed in a richtextbox, but i don't know how to add " in a string output, i have everything working except the displaying of ""; and its C# :) so it should look like that:

```
string test2 = "test2";
richTextBox.Text = "string test1 = " + (the ") + test2 + (the ") + ";";
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You are not supposed to ask multiple questions in one post. Please split them into multiple posts. Should you have any enquiries, please proceed to the help center. You just need to press the help drop down on the top of the page! Despite all that, I will try to answer your first question.

Comment: *stackoverflow has this 2 questions maximum limit so i decided to ask multiple questions in once* You shouldn't. There is rules, and they are made to be followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backslashes (`\`) to "escape" a quotation mark. So this string is actually `"`:

```
string s = "\"";
```

Got it? If you still don't, just remember that when ever you want to write a quotation in a string, write `\"`.

So your text would be something like this

```
richTextBox.Text = "string test1 = \"test2\";";
```

See? The outer most two quotes denote a string literal and the inner two quotes actually denote the actual quotes in the string. Also, don't forget the semicolon at the end. (You will be likely to forget this because you saw the semi colon in the string literal. But remember! The semicolon is in the string, it's "fake"!)

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the character " in your string. In C# in many other languages the escape key is `\`

So your final string will be :

```
richTextBox.Text = "string test1 = \"" + test2 + "\";";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by escaping the `"` like so `\"`:

```
richTextBox.Text = "string test1 = \"test2\";"
```

Which will display:

```
string test1 = "test2";
```